# How to bind SelectedItem (from a ListBox) to a Variable?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm working on my first WP7 App and this problem causes me some headache.

I've a ListBox defined like this

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemList}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="35" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" FontSize="15"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Binding the ItemsSource works fine, but the MySelectedItem-Property doesn't get updated when selecting an item. Is this function not implemented (like in WPF) or am I just doing something? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use -

`SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"` and it should be fine.

Comment: I'm unable to get this working on a WP7 project. Can anyone else verify that this does and should work on Windows Phone 7?

Comment: I'm wondering, how that should work, since the SelectedItems-property of a ListBox is a read-only property. It suppose to throw an Exception like "Cannot set read-only property System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.SelectedItems'."

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` for your ListBox.

Comment: No, Windows Mobile 7 uses some version of Silverlight 3 :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround.. I hope someone will post a more elegant solution.

XAML:

```
 <ListBox Name="DecksListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsList}"
          SelectionChanged="UpdateSelectedItem"
```

Code-behind:

```
    private void UpdateSelectedItem(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ignore if there is no selection
        if (DecksListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;
        App.ViewModel.MySelectedItem = App.ViewModel.MyItemsList[DecksListBox.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

Maybe this might help someone in the meantime.